# Error when attempting post hoc analyses on a binomial glm with interactions

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

[link to data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aMgwSPOZAEO3cICqLeQyqsDF_5WrhFXe)

I am having a problem conducting post hoc analyses on a binomial glm using the data linked above.

Experiment: I am looking at the detectability (presence/absence) of an insect marker given 3 explanatory variables; application method (apptreat - factor, 2 levels), marker (factor, 2 levels), and exposure time (exp - numerical, 3 levels). Response variable (detect) is recorded as 1 for present and 0 for absent. After running the model several times to determine whether or not any interactions were significant, I came up with the following model.

Model:

```
id.glm2 <- glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+apptreat*exp, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec2)
anova(id.glm2, test="Chisq")
```

Output:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table
Model: binomial, link: logit
Response: detec
Terms added sequentially (first to last)


     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                           906    1182.37              
apptreat      1  238.847       905     943.52 < 2.2e-16 ***
marker        1  156.844       904     786.68 < 2.2e-16 ***
exp           1  138.098       903     648.58 < 2.2e-16 ***
apptreat:exp  1    9.414       902     639.17  0.002153 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would like to do a post hoc multiple comparison analysis to compare the differences within each variable including the interaction using the `glht` function in `multcomp` CRAN. I am able to get comparisons for the main effects with a warning about interactions being present (as expected from other posts). In order to perform posthoc analysis on the interaction I added a column to the data for the interaction using the following code and included it as a main effect in the `glm` model

```
indiv_detec2$AE <- interaction(indiv_detec2$apptreat, indiv_detec2$exp)
id.glm2 <- glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+AE, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec2)
anova(id.glm2, test="Chisq")
```

When I use the `glht()` function to do the posthoc analysis on the interaction variable (AE) it results with the following error message

```
glht(m1, linfct = mcp(AE = "Tukey"))
Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match
```

The data is unbalanced but I don't see how that would prevent the posthoc on the interaction variable and not the other variables. I know this problem has been brought up on other posts but I haven't been able to get the solutions mentioned in those posts to work. I'm assuming it's something I am doing wrong/simple mistake and just can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**
I have tested the model with the all data as factors and where "exp" (exposure time) and "detec" (detection) are continuous. Both ways result in the same error messages being generated, however, different interactions are detected as being significant depending on how the data is classified. Knowing this, I will continue to use the model above for simplicity since the problem remains the same

When attempting the `glht()` function using the model

```
id.glm3<-glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+apptreat*exp+marker*exp, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec2)
summary(glht(id.glm3, linfct = mcp(app = "Tukey")))
```

I am unable to run the test on the interaction (which is normal for `glht()` and `mcp()` functions) and the warning message below appears when running the test on the main effects "apptreat" and "exp".

> Warning message:
>       In mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate
>
> Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match

The summary output looks like this

```
Call:
glm(formula = detec ~ marker + apptreat + exp + apptreat * exp, 
family = binomial, data = indiv_detec2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0545  -0.5493  -0.1415   0.6164   3.1055  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -4.8141     0.3672 -13.111  < 2e-16 ***
markerMilk             2.7846     0.2365  11.774  < 2e-16 ***
apptreatLitter         3.6469     0.4933   7.394 1.43e-13 ***
exp24                  0.2145     0.4038   0.531    0.595    
exp48                  3.0381     0.3948   7.696 1.41e-14 ***
apptreatLitter:exp24  -0.2675     0.5697  -0.469    0.639    
apptreatLitter:exp48       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1182.37  on 906  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  623.15  on 901  degrees of freedom
AIC: 635.15

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

When I amend the data set to include a column representing the interaction as suggested in other posts and run the model with the interaction as a main effect

```
indiv_detec2$AE<-interaction(indiv_detec$apptreat, indiv_detec$exp)

id.glm3<-glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+AE, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec2)
```

I get the following error message when running the `glht()` function

```
summary(glht(id.glm3, mcp(AE="Tukey")))
```

> Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match

The summary output looks like this

```
Call:
glm(formula = detec ~ marker + apptreat + exp + AE, family = binomial, 
    data = indiv_detec2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0545  -0.5493  -0.1415   0.6164   3.1055  

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -4.81408    0.36719 -13.111  < 2e-16 ***
markerMilk      2.78462    0.23650  11.774  < 2e-16 ***
apptreatLitter  3.64689    0.49325   7.394 1.43e-13 ***
exp24          -0.05294    0.57806  -0.092    0.927    
exp48           3.03810    0.39479   7.696 1.41e-14 ***
AEDirect.24     0.26748    0.56973   0.469    0.639    
AELitter.24          NA         NA      NA       NA    
AEDirect.48          NA         NA      NA       NA    
AELitter.48          NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

   Null deviance: 1182.37  on 906  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  623.15  on 901  degrees of freedom
AIC: 635.15

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I have read, and suspect, that whatever is causing the NA to appear in the summary output is the problem, but I have not seen an answer that clearly explains what's going on so I can fix the problem.

I hope this clarifies

Comment: It looks like your factors are being entered as continuous variables (notice the 1 df). Make sure you specify them as factors.

Comment: When I upload the file I change "apptreat" and "marker to factors, "exp" to numeric since these are hrs. after exposure, and keep the response variable "detec" as interger (1,0 = presence, absence). Are you suggesting that I treat "exp" and "detec" both as factors as well?

Comment: Even when I do this and have all variables as factors, I still get the error message "Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match" when running the glht() function. I don't understand what the error means.

Comment: It is fine to have things coded as you do but it means that there are no post hoc tests available for the interaction as it only has 1 degree of freedom (there is only 1 parameter begin estimated). This is the results of treating exp as continuous. Essentially you are testing whether the slope for exp differs between the two levels of appttreat.

Comment: I assume that you are wanting to test whether the effect of apptreat differs across the three levels of exp. You would need to treat exp as a factor to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have tried it with classifying all variables as factors as well. I've edited the question with an update in hopes things are a bit more clear. It looks like whatever is causing the NAs to appear in the summary output is likely what's responsible for the error message but I haven't found an explanation on what causes this and how to fix it. If I can't fix the data or model and get the `glht()` function to work, is there an alternative? I am looking at how all of the different variables, including interactions, affect marker detectability (detec).

Comment: I will also add that when "exp" is numeric, the error about the matrices not matching is only generated when I use the model with the interaction expressed as a main effect (AE) and not when the actual interaction (apptreat*exp) is included in the model.

Comment: First off, it would help to know what you are wanting to test. Second, you need to look at the cell sample sizes of the interaction (exp by apptest). Given the NAs in the second model, I suspect that you have an empty cell or no variability in the outcome. Third, you shouldn't need the post hoc procedure but rather should be able to test these through how you parameterize your model. The key is understanding how to interpret dummy coded coefficients when there is an interaction.

Comment: Ok. I'll start a new question specifically for the issue with N/A's in the summary output. since that looks like to root of the problem. Thanks for the guidance